# Split a string in a flexible manner with a regular expression

Tags: r, regex, string, split

Context: I need to split strings that are too long and that are used as column headers in an html table. Those strings are variable names, so they don't have any spaces in them.

If I let the css `max-width` property do the job, the string is split at a fixed place, not making use of the dots or `_`'s in the string.

For example, suppose I have this string:

```
this.is.a.long.string.indeed.yeah.well.you.know
```

Using the dots as separators, I can split it in many, many different ways. But I pose these guiding principles:

1. All substrings must be 12 characters or less
2. Separators [._] should be at the end, not at the beginning of a substring
3. The number of substrings must be minimal
4. If several solutions exist, the one having the most similar substring lengths is to be preferred.

I could do this programmatically with R, but I'm turning to regex wizards to see whether this is possible using solely regular expressions.

**What I have so far:**

Regex: `.{1,12}(_|\b|\Z)`

Results: `this.is.a. | long.string. | indeed.yeah. | well.you. | know`

It works well, except when there is a long sequence of letters without any separators. Please see [this example on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/XrJuYj/1/).

Ideally, separators would be used whenever possible, and a fallback split would occur when there is a sequence longer than 12 characters without a separator.

Comment: If there's a word wrapper function (I don't know R), then you could replace the dots with space, let the function wrap it and replace spaces with dots after that.

Comment: `strwrap` is the word wrapper function

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion... It gives good results, it just necessitates a little more work to split sequences of 12 or more letters without separators.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were so close, you just need to present it with another alternative for cases where no separator is found:

```
.{1,12}(_|\b|\Z)|.{1,12}
```

Check it out: https://regex101.com/r/XrJuYj/2/

Edit: to ensure the split portion contains a non-separating character, you can use the following:

```
(?=.{1,12}(.*))(?=.*?[^\W_].*?[\W_].*?\1).{1,12}(?<=_|\b|\Z)|.{1,12}
```

See it at: https://regex101.com/r/XrJuYj/3

Comment: Thanks for your answer... There is just a little problem: one group consists of a single dot.

Comment: Ah, if that's a problem, if I've updated the regex with a tricky test to ensure that the first 12 characters actually contains a non-separator before a separator in order to avoid cases like that. If not, it goes to the fallback alternative.

Comment: A regex wizard you are indeed, dear sir. That works like a charm, thanks a lot!